# How do you combine columns with conditions in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks somewhat like this in R:

```
D = data.frame(countrycode = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
      year = c(1980, 1991, 2013, 1980, 1991, 2013), 
      pop90 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
      pop00 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
      pop10 = c(5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6))
```

desired output:

```
Res = data.frame(countrycode = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
       year = c(1980, 1991, 2013, 1980, 1991, 2013),
       popcombined = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6))
```

I would like to combine pop90, pop00 and pop10 into one column where years 1980-1990 would reflect the value of pop90, years 1991-2000 would reflect the value of pop00 and years 2001-2013 would reflect the value of pop10. How can I do this? I have tried the merge function but I could not set the years in place to reflect the conditions I set out above.

Comment: Please make your example more representative and provide your desired output.

Comment: @David: I'm not sure what you mean by making the example more representative but I have edited in the desired output. Thanks for your input; I'm quite new here.

Comment: I mean that instead of `...` put some real values that will best represent the problem. In you case, column `year` is longer than the rest of the columns, for example. It would be also nice if `pop90`, `pop00` and `pop10` didn't have exactly same values, so your desired output will make more sense.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I hope that makes more sense now. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Google `reshape` in R. You will find many questions along with answers.

Comment: `D$popcombined <- ifelse(D$year < 1991, D$pop90, ifelse(D$year>2000, D$pop10, D$pop00))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row/col` indexing

```
popcombined <- D[3:5][cbind(1:nrow(D),findInterval(D$year, 
             c(-Inf, 1990, 2000, Inf)))]

cbind(D[1:2], popcombined)
#    countrycode year popcombined
#1           2 1980           1
#2           2 1991           3
#3           2 2013           5
#4           3 1980           2
#5           3 1991           4
#6           3 2013           6
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get this error when using your code though "Error in cbind:nrow(D) : NA/NaN argument."

Comment: @rbeginner Using the example you posted, I am not getting an error.  I used `R 3.2.0`  Can you show a reproducible example that gives error

Comment: Sorry, I must have done something wrong because it works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` and do something like:

```
library(plyr)

adply(D, 1, function(u){
    transform(u[,1:2], 
              pop = cut(u$year, c(1980, 1990, 2000, 2013), label=tail(unlist(u),3),include.lowest=T))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I set all unwanted data to `NA` and `melt`ed from package `reshape2`:

```
## Set NA's for every decade

library(Hmisc)

D[D$year %nin% 1980:1989,]$pop90 <- NA

D[D$year %nin% 1990:1999,]$pop00 <- NA

D[D$year %nin% 2000:2013,]$pop10 <- NA

# Melt data.frame
library(reshape2)

D.new <- melt(D, id.vars = c("countrycode", "year"),
                 value.name = "popcombined")

# Some minor stuff
D.new <- na.omit(D.new)

D.new <- D.new[,-3]

D.new <- arrange(D.new, countrycode)

# Check my data against your result
> D.new == Res
     countrycode year popcombined
[1,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
[2,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
[3,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
[4,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
[5,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
[6,]        TRUE TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When using this code, I get the following error: Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, D$year %nin% 1946:1990) : could not find function "%nin%".

Comment: `%nin%` is an operator from `Hmisc` package meaning "not in". You could fix my code with something like `D[!(D'$year %in% 1980:1989),]$pop90`. This uses `%in%` which is available in base R.

Comment: `library(Hmisc)` should have been added to your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. That part works now but when setting NA's for every decade, I get the following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "pop90", value = NA) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Answer (score 0):

Using basic indexing:

```
D[D$year>=1980 & D$year<1990 , "popcombined" ] <- D[D$year>=1980 & D$year<1990, "pop90" ]
D[D$year>=1990 & D$year<2000 , "popcombined" ] <- D[D$year>=1990 & D$year<2000, "pop00" ]
D[D$year>=2000  , "popcombined" ] <- D[D$year>=2000 , "pop10" ]
```

Using `with`:

```
D$popcombined2 <-NA
D$popcombined2 <- with(D, ifelse( year>=1980 & year<1990, pop90, popcombined2 ))
D$popcombined2 <- with(D, ifelse( year>=1990 & year<2000, pop00, popcombined2 ))
D$popcombined2 <- with(D, ifelse( year>=2000 , pop10, popcombined2 ))

#> D
#  countrycode year pop90 pop00 pop10 popcombined popcombined2
#1           2 1980     1     3     5           1            1
#2           2 1991     1     3     5           3            3
#3           2 2013     1     3     5           5            5
#4           3 1980     2     4     6           2            2
#5           3 1991     2     4     6           4            4
#6           3 2013     2     4     6           6            6
```

Comment: This will be a lot of lines if there are a couple more decades

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when using the following code, I get results, however, the results are not reflective of the values of either pop90, pop00 and pop10 in popcombined or pop combined 2-- they either show NAs or a number that is unrelated to any of the values.